# How to hand out a number randomly between variables in Java?

Tags: java, variables, random

**I want to hand out the number 5 randomly between 4 variables.**

e.g:

BEFORE:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
int d = 0;
```

AFTER:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 0;
int c = 1;
int d = 2;
```

or

```
int a = 0;
int b = 3;
int c = 0;
int d = 2;
```

or anything,  but the most important is that the `a+b+c+d` has to equal 5 .

**Thank you for your answer!**

Comment: Have you tried to google "java random number"?

Comment: How random do the numbers have to be? You could keep track of the current sum, and chose a random number for the next variable a between current sum and 5. That will have the tendency to have 0's at the end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You set `a` to a random number between `0` and `5`.
2. You set `b` to a random number between `0` and `5 - a`
3. You set `c` to a random number between `0` and `5 - a - b`
4. You set `d` to `5 - a - b - c`

As a result, you get 4 numbers with a sum of 5.

So as not to be boring and repeat tons of questions on Stack Overflow about finding a number in a given range, which would be a sub-task there, here's a link: [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)

Comment: Caution: This will not make the numbers evenly distributed as c will most likely have a smaller range of numbers to pick from than a.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
    Random random =  new Random();

    int a = random.nextInt(5);
    int b = random.nextInt(5 - a);
    int c = random.nextInt(5 - a - b);
    int d = 5 - (a + b + c);

    System.out.print("a : " + a  +
            "\nb : " + b+
            "\nc : " + c+
            "\nd : " + d +
            "\n\nTotal : " + (a+b+c+d)); \\total will be 5
```